# Unable to create a VIEW in Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

I am trying to create a view on Apache Ignite using the following syntax:

```
emplCache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(
            "CREATE VIEW EmployeeCopy AS (SELECT * FROM Employee);")).getAll();
```

(Assume that table Employee is available and has data in it).
When this line gets executed, I get the following exception:

```
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: null
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:1823)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:795)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:765)
at com.demo.ignite.test1.EmployeeQuery2.createCopyTable(EmployeeQuery2.java:71)
at com.demo.ignite.test1.EmployeeQuery2.main(EmployeeQuery2.java:55)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: null
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2316)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:1820)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryDistributedSqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1343)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$5.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1815)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$5.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1813)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2293)
... 5 more
```

I see that the variable "twoStepQry" is null at line 1343 of class IgniteH2Indexing.java. I am not able to understand if I have missed something.

I am using apache-ignite-2.1.0.

Also if I create a VIEW, how does it work internally? Does it lock on those entries in the cache, or does it copy it to some other cache?

Answer (score 1):

Ignite does not support CREATE VIEW for now.
I have created a ticket for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5951

List of supported DDL statements can be found at https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-ddl